# Puppeteer can not listen service worker's console

Tags: mocha.js, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, puppeteer

I use mocha + puppeteer to test a website with service worker.

But I can't get these console from service worker.

```
// in puppeteer, console event listener
page.on('console', msg => {
  console.log(msg.text());
});

// in service-worker js file
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  console.log('installing…');
});
```

How can I do?

Comment: I don't work a lot with puppeter but something a little tricky that you can do is use `postMessage` to communicate your log into `document` and log it from there

Comment: Is this for an offline test?

Comment: No, it's not an offline test, it's an online test

Comment: @ekans It seems like a good solution. But I still wonder is there any way to catch the console from service worker without modifying code of web.

Comment: Service workers are run in a different process so I doubt the default `page.on` will work. Maybe you can use remote debugging to access the logs from service worker.